# Resort key-Value combination

Tags: excel, vba

The following example just shows the pattern, my data much bigger.
I have a Table like

```
| Variable | String |
|:---------|-------:|
| V1       | Hello  |   
| V2       | little |
| V3       | World  |
```

I have another table where different arrangements are defined

```
| Arrangement1 | Arrangement2 |
|:-------------|-------------:|
| V3           | V2           |   
| V2           | V1           |
| V1           | V3           |
```

My output depending on the asked Arrangement (e.g. Arrangement1) should be

```
| Variable | Value |
|:---------|------:|
| V3       | World |   
| V2       | little|
| V1       | Hello |
```

Till now I try to realize an approach with .find and array but think there might be an easier way (maybe with dictionary?) anyone an idea with good performance?

Comment: `Application.Vlookup` for vba, or simple `Vlookup` as plain formula

Comment: Oh! You can assign an array as argument to Vlookup. Thanks for the hint!